# I'm trying to open any program file via python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to open a file via my python project, but it doesn't work.. Is there any reason why?

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

def openfile():

   window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="Open file", filetypes=(("exe files", "*.exe"),("all files", "*.*"))
    file_opener = open(window.filename)
    file_opener.read()

Button = Button(window, text="Open", command=openfile)
Button.pack()
```

Comment: you could use os and execute a batch command to run the script selected like this: os.system("python C:\\yourpath..\\file.py")

Comment: What you are trying to do next? What should happen after open it?

Answer (score 0):

To run a file, use `os.system([file path])`. That runs the command `[file path]` which runs the file.

For example, if you have a file in your desktop name `test.py`, typing `os.system("C:\Users\[username]\desktop\test.py")` runs the file `test.py`.

There is a code which runs a file chosen by user:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import os

path = askopenfilename()

os.system(path)
```

But if the path contains spaces, add the following code just before `os.system(path)`:

```
for character in path:
    if character == ' ':    # space detected?
        path = ('\"'        # add " at the beginning
               + path       # add the path
               + '\"')      # add " at the end
        break

print(path)                 # check if the path is corrected
```